# Arzelá-Ascoli Theorem precompact sets

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sequence-of-function, arzela-ascoli

Is the Arzelá-Ascoli Theorem true in a precompact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$?. If $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is precompact and we have a sequence $(f_n)$ of functions in $C(S)$ (Space of bounded and continuous functions $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$) which is equicontinuous and uniformly bounded, is there a subsequence of $(f_n)$ uniformly convergent?

I think that if $S=(a,b)$, with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, we can extend continuously each function $f_n$ to $[a,b]$ and apply Arzelá-Ascoli Theorem in $C([a,b])$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider $f_n(x) = x^n$ on $(0,1)$. You'd need uniform equicontinuity. If you have that, you can extend all functions continuously to $\overline{S}$ and the extended family is still equicontinuous.

Comment: @DanielFischer So is the op's proposition true? I can't quite follow your comment: On one hand you state: "You'd need uniform equicontinuity." But you continue with "If you have that". With "that" do you mean equicontinuity?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik The "that" in "If you have that" is _uniform_ equicontinuity. With uniform equicontinuity each $f_n$ is uniformly continuous and thus has a continuous extension, call it $g_n$, to $\overline{S}$. The sequence of extensions is then also equicontinuous [and since $\overline{S}$ is compact, _uniformly_ equicontinuous] and uniformly, hence pointwise, bounded. By Ascoli-Arzelà it has a uniformly convergent subsequence, and the corresponding subsequence of the $f_n$ converges uniformly on $S$. Just equicontinuity is not enough. The example in my first comment shows that.

Comment: That the sequence is uniformly bounded is rather obvious. That it is equicontinuous follows easily from the **locally** uniform convergence of $f_n' \colon x \mapsto n\cdot x^{n-1}$ to $0$ on $S = (0,1)$, and that no subsequence converges uniformly on $S$ follows from the pointwise convergence to $0$ and $\lim_{x \to 1} f_n(x) = 1$ for all $n$. One point that muddies the waters is that many authors only consider compact domains when they introduce equicontinuity, and since _there_ there is no difference between the concepts of equicontinuity and uniform equicontinuity omit the word "uniform".